# How to set autologin support in yocto

Tags: yocto

I am currently working on yocto, during rootfs it is coming until login prompt, i dont want to do login.

```
i want to have autologin support How can i add autologin support in yocto
Already tried with "allow-empty-password"

and "debug-tweaks", which is useful for empty password not empty login or autologin
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for an image that uses systemd's getty:

https://github.com/ostroproject/ostro-os/blob/master/meta-ostro/classes/ostro-image.bbclass#L465

```
# Enable local auto-login of the root user (local = serial port and
# virtual console by default, can be configured).
OSTRO_LOCAL_GETTY ?= " \
    ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${systemd_system_unitdir}/serial-getty@.service \
    ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${systemd_system_unitdir}/getty@.service \
"
local_autologin () {
    sed -i -e 's/^\(ExecStart *=.*getty \)/\1--autologin root /' ${OSTRO_LOCAL_GETTY}
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FEATURES', 'autologin', 'local_autologin;', '', d)}"
```

It is tied to an image feature, and we took great care to avoid accidentally enabling it in production images:

- https://github.com/ostroproject/ostro-os/blob/master/meta-ostro/conf/local.conf.sample#L286
- https://github.com/ostroproject/ostro-os/blob/master/meta-ostro/conf/distro/include/ostro-os-development.inc#L4

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the login prompt by using something similar to this: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2005-June/014725.html

```
tty0::respawn:-/bin/sh
ttymxc1::resapwn:/sbin/getty ttymxc1 115200 vt100
```